# Launch VSCode into devcontainer session

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

It appears that the only way to run [devcontainers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) locally is by following these steps:

1. Open your codebase in VSCode
2. Reopen VSCode / The application in a devcontainer via command or the "Reopen in Container" popup

I would like to skip step 1 and launch VSCode directly into a container session. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now officially supported in the [devcontainer CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainer-cli).

After installing the CLI, the project can be opened directly in a devcontainer using the command:

```
devcontainer open .
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2133) you can call the `code` command with according arguments, e.g. from your project folder (on a Mac)

```
p=$(echo -n "$PWD"|xxd -p -c 256) && code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://dev-container+${p/[[:space:]]/}/workspace"
```

(where `/workspace` ist the remote workspace folder)

For more information see the issue.